# Symfony Fos User Bundle Controller overriding

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Hi i am trying to override FOSUserBundle Registration Controller in order to have two types of users and two different forms

I have the error :

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::__construct(), 0 passed in /Users/Antoine/Desktop/HC/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php on line 195 and exactly 4 expected
```

Here is my Controller

```
namespace Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Controller;


class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{


/**
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
    $user->setEnabled(true);
    $user->addRole("ROLE_PRO");

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    $form = $this->formFactory->create(new ProRegistrationType());
    $form->setData($user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

            $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            return $response;
        }

        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

        if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            return $response;
        }
    }

    return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/register.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

}

I went on focuserbundle documentation and they are only talking about overriding controller in the 1.3 version of FOSuserbundle
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To override FosUserBundle Controller you should to declares a child of FOSUserBundle. I do not understand why do you have constructor? You have container in container you have everything that you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The constructor was a mistake. I don't understand where the error comes from